charge_control_end_threshold randomly appears and disappear on Ubuntu 22.04
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.5 with kernel 6.8.0-45-generic and currently experiencing this strange issue: the charge_control_end_threshold entry will randomly be available and then disappear on next boot, and as such I'm not able to effectively limit my charging threshold. Note that most of the time it is not available.
System specs:
   OS: Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS x86_64
   Host: ROG Zephyrus G14 GA403UV_GA403UV 1.0
   Kernel: 6.8.0-45-generic
   DE: GNOME 42.9
   CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 8945HS w/ Radeon 780M Graphics (16) @ 4.000GHz
   GPU: NVIDIA 01:00.0 NVIDIA Corporation Device 28e0
   GPU: AMD ATI 65:00.0 Device 1900
   Memory: 4036MiB / 31378MiB
Result when running ls /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1(and charge_control_end_threshold will randomly appear here):
alarm               charge_now   manufacturer   status      voltage_min_design
capacity            current_now  model_name     subsystem   voltage_now
capacity_level      cycle_count  power          technology
charge_full         device       present        type
charge_full_design  hwmon2       serial_number  uevent

Battery info:
--- TLP 1.5.0 --------------------------------------------

+++ Battery Care
Plugin: asus
Supported features: none available
Driver usage:
* natacpi (asus_wmi) = inactive (laptop not supported)

+++ Battery Status: BAT1
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/manufacturer                   = ASUS 
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/model_name                     = A32-K55
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/cycle_count                    =      0 (or not supported)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_full_design             =   4580 [mAh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_full                    =   4306 [mAh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_now                     =   4306 [mAh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/current_now                    =      0 [mA]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status                         = Full

Charge                                                      =  100.0 [%]
Capacity                                                    =   94.0 [%]

I have tried Ubuntu 24.04 together with kernel 6.10 and this is no longer an issue, but I'm not ready to move to 24.04 yet, and would prefer to stick with 22.04 for some time. I also understand that this is probably due to the newer hardware of my laptop as on another older laptop I have (also Asus ROG) this is not an issue.

This is a kernel issue. If your current kernel doesn't work, then you need 6.10 or a newer one. You won't be able to avoid it.
